# How to substitute a command output into a string and append that to a file (in Alpine Linux running in Docker)

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 9050 9051
RUN apk --update add tor
RUN echo "ControlPort 9051" >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN password_hash=$(tor --hash-password "foo")
RUN echo "HashedControlPassword $password_hash" >> /etc/tor/torrc
CMD ["tor"]
```

I'm trying to add the line `HashedControllPassword [pw]` to /etc/tor/torrc, where `[pw]` is generated by the command `tor --hash-password "foo"`. (I'm using "foo" as password in this example).

If I build the image using `docker build --tag my_tor .` and enter the command line using

```
docker run -it my_tor /bin/ash
```

and run `cat /etc/tor/torrc`, I see

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword
```

In other words, in the end the `torrc` doesn't seem to contain the hashed password. However, similar commands in my Ubuntu terminal do work. Can anyone spot what the problem is?

Comment: Use `ENV password_hash xxx` or something similar, as What you do is only valid in this RUN and not later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 9050 9051
ARG password
RUN apk --update add tor
RUN echo "ControlPort 9051" >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo "HashedControlPassword $(tor --hash-password $password)" >> /etc/tor/torrc
CMD ["tor"]
```

And then build using:

```
docker build --build-arg password=foo Dockerfile
```

In general I would not bake password in an image. It would be better to provide those things when you run the container using `-e`.

Comment: With this Dockerfile the second line of `/etc/tor/torrc` ends up as `HashedControlPassword Apr 28 15:11:03.587 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
16:B93F54A5908CE0D7600AA8DA98933FD4BA5F903A71A83B776B1EF7F52A`. So an entire warning message has been accidentally included. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, the warning can be suppressed by using Tor's `--quiet` argument: `tor --quiet --hash-password "foo"`.